# Nature of series of a recurrent sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ recursively by $x_1>0$ and $x_{n+1}=\arctan(x_n)$, for all $n\geq1$. Study the nature of the series $\Sigma \sin(x_n)$. ${}{}{}{}$

What I managed to do so far:

Using the inequality $\arctan(x)<x$ it can be shown that $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ decreases strictly to zero. And using fundamental limits $\sin(x)/x$ and L'Hospital's rule I showed that the ratio $\frac{\sin(x_{n+1})}{\sin(x_n)}$ converges to $1$ and is strictly smaller than $1$, which makes the ratio test unusable, any hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that for $x$ close to $0$, you have $\displaystyle \arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)$. From that we get easily that $x_{n+1}\sim x_n$ as $n\to +\infty$, and $\displaystyle x_n-x_{n+1}\sim \frac{x_n^3}{3}$. Now put $\displaystyle y_n=\frac{1}{x_{n+1}^2}-\frac{1}{x_n^2}$. Show that $y_n$ has a finite limit $L$. Now use Cesaro's theorem: if $u_n\to L$, then $\displaystyle \frac{u_1+\cdots+u_n}{n}\to L$ for $u_n=y_n$. This gives you a simple equivalent for $x_n$, and it is easy to finish.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late response. We have $L=2/3$ and the series is equivalent to sum of $1/\sqrt{n}$ which is known to diverge.